# Download json to local storage from an api request in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, api, storage

how can i download a json from an api to my local storage using angularjs. 
I have an array of data that i want to store in my computer but don't know how to save it. I know how to get the data and view it in browser using

```
angular.module("myModule",[])
.controller('myController',['$scope','$http',function(response){
  $http.get(json file url).then(function(response){
    console.log(response)
  })

}])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the json in the localstorage like:

```
angular.module("myModule",[])
.controller('myController',['$scope','$http',function(response){
  $http.get(json file url).then(function(response){
    localStorage.setItem('jsonResult', response);
  })
}])
```

And while getting the value you can do:

```
var response = localStorage.getItem('jsonResult');
```